# Bridge Pattern:: decouples abstraction from implementation so that both can vary independently

Tags: design-patterns

In Bridge pattern i have read **"decouples abstraction from implementation so that both can vary independently".** what does it mean really ? and how does this phrase related to the Bridge pattern example given below? 
i understand this code but unable to relate this code with phrase. can anyone explain this.

Thanks.

```
/* Implementor interface*/    


interface Gear    
{
 void handleGear();
}

/* Concrete Implementor - 1 */

class ManualGear implements Gear{

public void handleGear(){

    System.out.println("Manual gear");
}
}

/* Concrete Implementor - 2 */

class AutoGear implements Gear{

public void handleGear(){
    System.out.println("Auto gear");
}
}

/* Abstraction (abstract class) */

abstract class Vehicle {
Gear gear;

public Vehicle(Gear gear){

    this.gear = gear;
}

abstract void addGear();
}

   /* RefinedAbstraction - 1*/

    class Car extends Vehicle{

public Car(Gear gear){

    super(gear);

    // initialize various other Car components to make the car
}

public void addGear(){

    System.out.print("Car handles ");

    gear.handleGear();

    }
}

/* RefinedAbstraction - 2 */

class Truck extends Vehicle{

public Truck(Gear gear){

    super(gear);

    // initialize various other Truck components to make the car

}

public void addGear(){
    System.out.print("Truck handles " );
    gear.handleGear();
}
}

/* Client program */

public class BridgeDemo {  

public static void main(String args[]){

    Gear gear = new ManualGear();

    Vehicle vehicle = new Car(gear);

    vehicle.addGear();

    gear = new AutoGear();
    vehicle = new Car(gear);
    vehicle.addGear();

    gear = new ManualGear();
    vehicle = new Truck(gear);
    vehicle.addGear();

    gear = new AutoGear();
    vehicle = new Truck(gear);
    vehicle.addGear();
}
}

output
Car handles Manual gear
Car handles Auto gear
Truck handles Manual gear
Truck handles Auto gear
```

Answer (score 0):

> "decouples abstraction from implementation so that both can vary independently"

In this specific code example, this means that `Vehicle` class only depends on the `Gear` interface, not on the specific implementations of it. This decouples the *contract* (how various vehicles use various gears, i.e. by calling `handleGear()`) from the private implementation of different types of gears.

In more practical terms, it means that changes to `Gear` implementations do not require to recompile the code where `Vehicle` is defined, as long as the interface stays the same. You can perfectly add a new type of gear and pass it to the same existing vehicle - the contract is unchanged and the actual implementation can be determined at runtime.

Same holds for `Vehicle`: you can keep changing the private implementations of them, as long as the way `Gear` is used doesn't change. Hence, both `Gear` and `Vehicle` implementations can vary independently.

Comment: Hi Alexander Tsvetkov,  thanks for the reply. i think this is the best answer. and now i am able to understand this concept completely. again thanks.

Comment: @mukeshsingh, I glad that it helped! Please consider upvoting and marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: Why not Alexander ! i will surly do that but how to do ?. i am new in stackoverflow. don't know about upvoting and how to mark as accepted.